# Using Pandas to Pivot Data

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I currently have a dataset that is structured like so:

```
ID     ProgramCode     ProgramType     
001    0001            Major
001    0423            Minor
002    3203            Major
002    5893            Minor
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to use Pandas to Pivot the data to produce an output like:

```
ID     ProgramCode_1         ProgramType_1      ProgramCode_2       ProgramType_2
001    0001                  Major              0423                Minor
002    3203                  Major              5893                Minor
```

I have tried various parameters using

```py
df.pivot()
```

with no success.

Is there a better Pandas function to essentially search the DF for unique IDs and then fill in columns across a single row?

Comment: Check question 10 and 11

Comment: use: `new_df = df.pivot_table(index = 'ID',
                        columns = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1),
                        values = ['ProgramCode', 'ProgramType'],
                        aggfunc='first').sort_index(axis=1,level=1)` and then 
`new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}'  for x,y in new_df.columns]`